# MySQL No current query in DataReader

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datareader

I have a list that automatically fills when I start the program:

```
lstTrabajadores.Items.Clear()
    ServerConnection()
    Try
        Dim MyCommand As New MySqlCommand("select * from caburga.trabajadores", MyConnection)
        Dim MyReader As MySqlDataReader
        MyReader = MyCommand.ExecuteReader
        If MyReader.HasRows Then
            While MyReader.Read
                lstTrabajadores.Items.Add(MyReader.GetString("nombreCompleto"))
            End While
        Else
            lstTrabajadores.Items.Add("No hay trabajadores registrados.")
        End If
        MyReader.Close()
        MyReader.Dispose()
        MyConnection.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MsgBox("Error " & Environment.NewLine & ex.Message & Environment.NewLine & "Contáctese con el administrador del sistema.")
    Finally
        MyConnection.Dispose()
    End Try
```

Now, I've closed and disposed every reader I've used. The thing is I want to fill text fields with the data linked to the list content.

The program works as follows, I start the program, it fills the list, I click on the list item and I get a "No current query in data reader" VB.Net error, and a "There's already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first", MySQL exception.

This is the list selected index changed code for when I click a list item:

```
Try
        ServerConnection()
        Dim MyCommand As New MySqlCommand("select * from caburga.trabajadores where nombreCompleto= '" & lstTrabajadores.SelectedItem & "'", MyConnection)
        Dim MyReader As MySqlDataReader
        MyReader = MyCommand.ExecuteReader
        MyReader.Read()
        txtRUT.Text = MyReader.GetInt32("rut")
        txtDV.Text = MyReader.GetInt32("dv") <<THIS IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR.>>
        txtNombreTrabajador.Text = MyReader.GetString("nombreTrabajador")
        txtApellido1Trabajador.Text = MyReader.GetString("apellidoPaterno")
        txtApellido2Trabajador.Text = MyReader.GetString("apellidoMaterno")
        MyReader.Close()
        MyReader.Dispose()
        MyConnection.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MsgBox("Error " & Environment.NewLine & ex.Message & Environment.NewLine & "Contáctese con el administrador del sistema.")
    Finally
        MyConnection.Dispose()
    End Try
```

Can anyone, please, point out my error. If you need to see more of my code I'll gladly update this question.

I appreciate any kind of help.

**UPDATE:** I open my connection to MySQL on ServerConnection(), which is a function on a module.

```
Function ServerConnection()
    Try
        MyConnection.ConnectionString = "server=myip;user=root;password=password;database=caburga"
        MyConnection.Open()
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: You should wrap your connections and command in `using blocks`. Also you should change your read code to `Do While orderReader.Read` followed by `loop`

Comment: You didnt close (or dispose) of the Command and Connection objects.  Everything which implements a `Dispose` method should be used in a `using` block.

Comment: **WARNING**: This code has severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com) because you're not properly [escaping values](http://bobby-tables.com/asp).

Comment: tadman, I know what SQL injection is, and I know how to prevent I just won't do it now. Please refrain to the question.

Comment: Do you open the connection in SelectedIndexChanged or in the ServerConnection?

Comment: Woops. Sorry. I added that info.